# Number of CPU sockets, or location of SMBIOS on OS X

Tags: macos, cpu

I would like to find the number of cpu sockets on OS X machines. This information is normally in the SMBIOS on pc's. Newer Intel Macs use EFI but I have read that the EFI does also contain an SMBIOS block.

I therefore appear to need access to the SMBIOS data block on power pc machines, and the EFI, SMBIOS section on Intel macs. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: On intel machines I read smbios from the IOKit and parse the tables. Unfortuantly mac minis say they have two sockets and two processors, therefore the smbios is inacurate.

Comment: can you get the address of smbios entry point table on EFI macs?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any specific API for this (although there probably is one), but at the console, you can run this command and get the answer to be parsed out:

```
>system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
```

Comment: Does not seem to include the number of cores in there.

Comment: Hmm. Running that command on my MacBook correctly shows the number of processors (1) and the number of cores (2).

Comment: Beg pardon, I meant cpu sockets. It does show the number of processors and cores.

Comment: Ahhh. Yes, I suppose you could have unpopulated sockets.